# can you tell me this font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I am trying to figure out this font. I can't get Whatthefont to come up with one like this.

Answer (score 6):

Looks similar to **[Stink on the Death](https://www.dafont.com/stink-on-the-death.font?text=Glory)** by Maelle.K.

[image]